# Node.js Script on GitHub Pages or Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, github-pages, airtable

I'm wondering if I can run a Node.js script in my Jekyll page from GitHub Pages or Amazon S3? I think it can't run on GitHub Pages since it doesn't support server side code. Not too sure. The code is below:

```
var Airtable = require('airtable');
var base = new Airtable({apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY'}).base('appAnZVyYqusNPV5Q');

base('Invitee list').select({
    // Selecting the first 3 records in Complete list:
    maxRecords: 3,
    view: "Complete list"
}).eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
    // This function (`page`) will get called for each page of records.

    records.forEach(function(record) {
        console.log('Retrieved', record.get('Email'));
    });

    // To fetch the next page of records, call `fetchNextPage`.
    // If there are more records, `page` will get called again.
    // If there are no more records, `done` will get called.
    fetchNextPage();

}, function done(err) {
    if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
});
```

Comment: GitHub pages is a definite no.  You likely _could_ make the API call from the client side, but you'd be exposing your Airtable API Key for all to see which is not wise.

Comment: S3 is a definite no, for the same reason as mentioned here (just swap out PHP for Node.js -- the reason is identical). https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/105921/36028